# Why is React hook version of code hitting max call stack error, but class version isn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

I wrote a class component that seemed to work fine and didn't run into any errors. I then tried switching it over to use Hooks because I wanted to take advantage of useContext later. However, now in the Hooks version of my code, I'm running into a max call stack error and I don't know how to fix it.

**Here's the original class component version that worked:**

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentItemIndex: 0,
      carouselFocused: false,
    };
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props, prevState: State) {
    if (prevState.carouselFocused !== this.state.carouselFocused) {
      if (this.state.carouselFocused === true) {
        this.subscription = leftEventEmitter$.subscribe(value => {
          this.setState((state, props) => ({
            currentItemIndex: loop(state.currentItemIndex - 1, 0, props.data.length - 1),
          }));
        });
        this.subscription.add(
          rightEventEmitter$.subscribe(value =>
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
              currentItemIndex: loop(state.currentItemIndex + 1, 0, props.data.length - 1),
            }))
          )
        );
      }
    }
    if (this.subscription) {
      if (!this.state.carouselFocused) {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: Props, state: State) {
    if (props.focused !== state.carouselFocused) {
      return {
        carouselFocused: props.focused,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
  private subscription?: Subscription;
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

**Here's the Hooks version that runs into the max call stack error:**

```
const [currentItemIndex, setCurrentItemIndex] = useState(0);
const [carouselFocused, setCarouselFocused] = useState(false);
let subscription: Subscription;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.focused !== carouselFocused) {
      setCarouselFocused(props.focused);
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (carouselFocused === true) {
      subscription = leftEventEmitter$.subscribe(value => {
        setCurrentItemIndex(prevState => loop(prevState - 1, 0, props.data.length - 1));
      });
      subscription.add(
        rightEventEmitter$.subscribe(value => {
          setCurrentItemIndex(prevState => loop(prevState + 1, 0, props.data.length - 1));
        })
      );
    }
    return () => {
      if (subscription) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  }, [carouselFocused]);
```

**The error shows the loop code:**

```
export function loop(value: number, min: number, max: number): number {
  const range = max - min + 1;
  if (value < min) {
    return loop(value + range, min, max);
  } else if (value > max) {
    return loop(value - range, min, max);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

**How do I fix the max call stack error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
setCurrentItemIndex(prevState => loop(prevState - 1, 0, props.data.length - 1));
```

with the original value of currentItemIndex = 0 and props.data.length = 0

Then you will call loop(-1, 0, -1) that will go into an infinite loop because range will be equal to 0

Comment: props.data.length = 6 in this case. Any other ideas of what could be the problem? I thought I was setting state the same way with hooks as I was in the class component. The main difference I see is getDerivedStateFromProps in class vs hooks version. I thought I accounted for that with the first useEffect though? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is also a difference with your subscription variable. In the class version, your subscription variable is created only once, so it's value is preserved between 2 updates. However in your functional version, subscription is created at every update, so you will lose the previous value. If you want to preserve the value of a variable  in a functional component, you need to use ref like this: const subscription = useRef();   then you can access it using subscription.current

Comment: The subscription in the functional version only updates when [carouselFocused] changes [React doc] (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) and then it unsubscribes when it unmounts. How would I useRef in this case because subscription is from rxjs and gives me the error: Property 'current' is missing in type 'Subscription' but required in type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' if I have subscription = useRef()

Comment: subscription is typed to Subscription, so you cannot assign it a ref. When you create a ref, the value is not the ref itself but ref.current. You could do something like this before your useEffect: const subscriptionRef = useRef();  Then you can assign it and use it like this:   subscriptionRef.current = leftEventEmitter$.subscribe(value => {...    subscriptionRef.current.unsubscribe()...

Comment: ugh, turns out at some point something was resetting props.data.length to 0 and when I hit that during a render it would call loop (-1, 0, -1). For this use case I ended up using useRef(props.data.length) and replaced props.data.length in my loop with ref.current. Thanks for your help HermitCrab!